# Grails not picking up compiled java .class files

Tags: java, grails

I'm moving my grails app to a new server, and run-app is failing (verbose stacktrace below).

The file grails claims to be missing ("AutocompleteEntity") is a java source file. It must be getting compiled because I see Autocomplete.class in the target directory.

I've tried all sorts of combinations of grails clean, rm'ing .grails, etc. with no luck. I'm bewildered!

```
shilad@gpu:~/macademia/Macademia$ grails run-app --stacktrace --verbose
Base Directory: /home/shilad/macademia/Macademia
| Configuring classpath
| Error SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/shilad/.m2/repository/org/grails/grails-plugin-log4j/2.3.7/grails-plugin-log4j-2.3.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/home/shilad/.m2/repository/org/slf4j/slf4j-jdk14/1.7.5/slf4j-jdk14-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
| Error SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
| Error SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
| Compiling 1 source files
| Compiling 1 source files.....
| Running Grails application
| Error Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:117)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:812)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.addArtefact(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:538)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.configureLoadedClasses(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:259)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsApplication.initialise(DefaultGrailsApplication.java:743)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.doCall(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:124)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader$_loadPlugins_closure2.doCall(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1254)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
    at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1086)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:910)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:411)
    at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:405)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.cli.api.BaseSettingsApi.profile(BaseSettingsApi.java:354)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.project.plugins.GrailsProjectPluginLoader.loadPlugins(GrailsProjectPluginLoader.groovy:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(GrailsPluginManagerFactoryBean.java:74)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1571)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1509)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:458)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:296)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:223)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:293)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:194)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:932)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:479)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:410)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:306)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:70)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:112)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4961)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5455)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1559)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1549)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor13.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at org.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrConstructorNewInstance(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:986)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ArtefactHandlerAdapter.newArtefactClass(ArtefactHandlerAdapter.java:108)
    ... 46 more
Caused by: java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type AutocompleteEntity not present
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:117)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:125)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.reifyTypeArguments(Reifier.java:68)
    at sun.reflect.generics.visitor.Reifier.visitClassTypeSignature(Reifier.java:138)
    at sun.reflect.generics.tree.ClassTypeSignature.accept(ClassTypeSignature.java:49)
    at sun.reflect.generics.repository.MethodRepository.getReturnType(MethodRepository.java:68)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.getGenericReturnType(Method.java:245)
    at java.beans.FeatureDescriptor.getReturnType(FeatureDescriptor.java:370)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getTargetEventInfo(Introspector.java:954)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:415)
    at java.beans.Introspector.getBeanInfo(Introspector.java:161)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:45)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:186)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.getPropertyDescriptors(BeanUtils.java:360)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.init(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:193)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.<init>(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:91)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:82)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.ClassPropertyFetcher.forClass(ClassPropertyFetcher.java:63)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AbstractGrailsClass.<init>(AbstractGrailsClass.java:84)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.AbstractInjectableGrailsClass.<init>(AbstractInjectableGrailsClass.java:29)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass.<init>(DefaultGrailsServiceClass.java:30)
    ... 51 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: AutocompleteEntity
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:648)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:758)
    at groovy.lang.GroovyClassLoader.loadClass(GroovyClassLoader.java:746)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:270)
    at sun.reflect.generics.factory.CoreReflectionFactory.makeNamedType(CoreReflectionFactory.java:114)
    ... 76 more
| Error Error loading plugin manager: Unable to locate constructor with Class parameter for class org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.DefaultGrailsServiceClass
| Error Forked Grails VM exited with error
| Server running. Browse to http://localhost:8080/Macademia
```

Comment: has your new box significant changed the java version?  can you run a ``grails clean`` first and then remove in your home ``~/.grails/.slcahce`` and try again?  might as well be old stuff you copied over.

Comment: I gave it a try, and no change. FWIW, the new box has java 7 and my dev box has java 6, but I rebuilt the grails project from source.

Comment: Is the mentioned class one of yours or from a plugin -- seems no grails default.  if it is one of yours, can you make sure, that the source is a) in a detected source directory (e.g. src/{lang}) b) that it's package is matching the directroy it is in and c) the class name is exactly the same as the filename.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. It is a class I created, and I verified it is in src/java with the correct package and file names. I can actually check the latter twice over because it is compiled to the correct directory within target/, so the compiler definitely recognizes it but it's not found at runtime. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

My grails 2.3.11 app (GGTS 3.6.4) after adding few values to an enum started to throw an exception (run-app --stacktrace --verbose):

```
Error loading plugin manager: Type <className> not present
java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type <className> not present
...
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: <className> 
...
Error loading plugin manager: Type <className> not present
```

After cleaning, deleting .grails and target folders I was able to run it one out of ten times. The enum was in src/java folder. The .class file was also in a target folder.

It started to work after I moved it to a different package.